# Is it not possible to have Custom domain in API Gateway with Lambda in VPC configured in serverless.yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

Following are the steps I did

1. Created a custom domain with Regional option and created a "A" record in route 53
2. Manually/through serverless configured my API mappings and tested. It works fine.
3. Now I tried to setup a VPC endpoint and configured the same in my serverless. But this time while deploy I get the below error

```
 An error occurred: ApiGatewayRestApi - You cannot change the endpoint of a RestApi to PRIVATE if there is a custom domain using it. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException
```

My Serverless.yml looks as below

```
custom:
customDomain:
  domainName: my-api.${opt:stage}.example.com
  basePath: 'v1'
  stage: ${opt:stage}
  createRoute53Record: true
  certificateName: ${env.CERTIFICATE}
.......

provider:
name: aws
endpointType: PRIVATE
vpcEndpointIds:
  - vpce-xxxxx
```

How can I address it ?

Comment: You have to remove your custom domain from your API. It does not make any sense to have a public domain for privet api, thus your conversion is blocked.

Comment: Okay thanks , then is there a way to define a domain name for my lambda functions, Say if i have 5 lambda functions and I want them to accessed using a user understandable domain name instead of what amazon gives to us ?

Comment: I think you could maybe use Route53's private hosted zone names.

Answer (score 0):

I finally achieved it using ALB and configuring the route 53 to the ALB and custom domain for adding the host while serving requests.
The below blog was very helpful
https://www.sentiatechblog.com/connecting-to-a-private-api-gateway-over-vpn-or-vpc-peering